# After updating compileSdk to version 33, part of the attributes in design stopped being displayed

Tags: android-studio

After updating the androidx.appcompat library:appcompat:1.5.1 to version 1.6.0 android studio gave me this error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqE8X.png)

I have updated compileSdk and versionSdk from version 32 to version 33. After that, most of the attributes were no longer displayed in the Design mode for the elements.

[attributes before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUIky.png) | [attributes after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9L8v.png)

build.gradle (app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gramzin.kilo"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1'
}
```

I tried changing the gradle version to 7.4.2 and the android gradle plugin version to 7.2.2, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated android studio and gradle to the latest version and everything worked